# Developer survey 2023: circular graphs?

Tags: discussion, survey

I was reading the 2023 developer survey, and saw these circular graphs showing intentions from one item to the next.  These are super neat, and I would like to use such a graph to illustrate concepts at work.

Example: https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-worked-with-vs-want-to-work-with-programming-scripting-and-markup-languages

Questions:

- what is the specific name for this type of representation?
- are there any online (or otherwise) tools or libraries to generate such graphs?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/what-is-this-type-of-circular-link-visualization-called

Comment: It's a [chord diagram](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/chord.html)

Comment: (Was this "[Stack Overflow Labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2023&utm_content=survey-results-sidebar)" thing (linked from the survey page) announced somewhere? *"Stack Overflow ... become the most visited, most trusted destination for developers in the world. ... Accuracy is fundamental. That comes from attributed, peer-reviewed sources that provide transparency. ... Humans should always be included in the application of any new technology."*)

Comment: OK, it is now [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390241/what-is-stack-overflow-labs/390243#390243).